# datatables showing incorrect pagination

Tags: datatables

Pagination should be showing `Showing 1 to 11 of 11 entries` instead it is showing `Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries`.  Here is my javascript:

```
$('.my-dashboard').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "searching": false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            ajax: "{{route('dashboard.getWork')}}",
            "language": {
                "infoFiltered": ""
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'title' },
                { data: 'category' }
            ]
        });
```

This is what is returned

```
{"draw":1,"iTotalRecords":11,"iTotalDisplayRecords":1,"aaData":[{"title":"Title","category":"1 Youtube Video"}]}
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation, see the "returned data" section of [this page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data). That shows the field names which DataTables expects to receive.

There is backwards-compatibility with [older legacy field names](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side).

However, that backwards compatibility only works if you use the old version of the DataTables `ajax` call:

> *Older versions of DataTables (1.9-) used a different set of parameters to send and receive from the server. As such scripts which are written for DataTables 1.10+ will not be able to function with DataTables 1.9-. However, DataTables 1.10 does have a compatibility mode for scripts written for 1.9-. This compatibility mode is triggered by use of the old `sAjaxSource` parameter (rather than the new `ajax` parameter) or by setting `$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;`.*

See [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Legacy) for that specific note.

Bottom line: If you can standardize on the new nomenclature, that should resolve this issue.